# Why doesn't Thorin die when he is stabbed by Azog?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, the-battle-of-the-five-armies

In the Hobbit movies, Thorin is stabbed by Azog two times: First in the **foot** and then the **chest**. The second stab was potentially fatal. Yet how did Thorin survive such a fatal stab, let alone have the strength to kill Azog  ?

Comment: The power of plot! He had to kill Azog, and so he did!

Comment: Dwarves are hardier than humans, evidently

Comment: He *does* die, though.

Comment: 'Tis but a scratch.

Comment: You *do* know, don't you, that much of the content of the *three* *Hobbit* movies was never in the book?  Have you checked this against the "same" events in the actual book?

Comment: @ZeissIkon My question is about the movie , not the book -_-

Comment: @Valorum Elves are considered superior to dwarves. Yet Lindir (an elf captain ) took a blow to the head and died in the movies  ( LotR:TwoTowers ) ..

Comment: Lindir's brain was damaged and Thorin's heart was damaged

Comment: So we have two arguments : Dwarves vs Elves.   &   Heart vs Brain

Comment: To make up for all the times when people die way too quickly in movies.

Answer (score 6):

He probably missed Thorin's heart and hit around his stomach. Here's the picture from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v8KtfHdBNrw) at 3:47

[image: Thorin stabbed]

In a human (and probably an orc), that's about where the heart would be, and so it would be reasonable to assume that this is **immediately** fatal. But Thorin is a dwarf, not a human. Assuming dwarves are simply more compact humans, that would probably move his heart up a bit.

Since Thorin is still alive but nearing death when Bilbo finds him, this would fit well with the assumption that this is a stomach wound. Those wounds lead to lots of internal bleeding and take a while to kill you.